# How to set empty and default value of a select element when using async pipes in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables, async-pipe

I'm trying to use async pipe in my Angular application, and this in my Typescript file:

```js
this.mySupplierList$ = this._mySupplierService.getSupplierList();
```

and the HTML file:

```html
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let supplier of supplierList$ | async" [ngValue]="supplier">{{supplier.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

I have two questions:

1. How can I set the default value of the select to the first or last supplier in mySupplierList?
2. How can I add an empty supplier item as the first element of the select?

Comment: i can not get in what you are doing in first option?

Comment: Is th the async pipe you don't get? It a way of binding the observable to the select, instead of using subscribe to get the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use ngModel to set a default value.
2. Add a  tag without any value for empty supplier item.

```html
<select  [(ngModel)]="yourModel">
  <option>Empty</option>
  <option *ngFor="let supplier of supplierList$ | async" [ngValue]="supplier">{{supplier.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-61411044) on stackblitz.

Comment: Thanks for replying, B45i! What I am looking for is how I can create a model (as an observable) for the selected value. The model has the last supplier in the list as an initial value. And regarding the empty element, is there a way to add it to the supplier list observable instead of just adding a static one?

Comment: @frank-jusnes   Created an example for you in stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-61411044.

I tried to use variable name that you used, but had to change it in few places as i don't have access to the exact API.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use ReactiveForms `FormControl` on the select input

```html
<select [formControl]="selectedSupplier">
  <option *ngFor="let supplier of supplierList$ | async" [ngValue]="supplier"
    >{{supplier.name}}</option
  >
</select>
```

And use the [setValue](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#replacing-a-form-control-value) function on the `FormControl` to set the initial value from the observable in a [tap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/do) pipe function

```js
selectedSupplier = new FormControl();

this.mySupplierList$ = this._mySupplierService.getSupplierList()
.pipe(
  tap((suppliers)=> {
    this.selectedSupplier.setValue(suppliers[suppliers.length - 1]);
  })
);
```

2. Manipulate the data in the observable using the RxJs [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map) function. Add an object to the array using the Javascript array [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) function.

```js
this.mySupplierList$ = this._mySupplierService.getSupplierList()
.pipe(
  map((suppliers)=> {
    suppliers.unshift({ id: null, name: "Select" });
    return suppliers;
  })
);
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cj-stackoverflow-61411044) with both the solutions